# how to get all domain class in spring boot with grails-datastore-gorm?

Tags: grails, spring-boot, grails-orm

I want to collect all domain class（implements GormEntity） in spring boot application ,just like grailsApplication.getArtefact in grails application ？
How to do ?

Comment: 1. ClassLoader getAllClasses
2. classes.each{ GormEntity.class.isAssignableFrom(it) }

it work and ugly,expect some api support this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the mapping context.

Once you have your datastore:

`datastore.getMappingContext().getPersistentEntities()`

Each persistent entity has a `getJavaClass()` method

Answer (score 0):

Thanks James Kleeh,his answer solve my problem.
So i post my code，hope it helps other people using GORM in spring-boot.

```
        ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext = (ConfigurableApplicationContext) applicationContext;
    configurableApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(Datastore).each{ String key, Datastore datastore ->
        if(datastore.class==org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore){
            println "hibernate datastore domains :"
            datastore.getMappingContext().persistentEntities.each{entity->
                println entity.javaClass.name
            }
        }
        if(datastore.class==org.grails.datastore.gorm.neo4j.Neo4jDatastore){
            println "neo4j datastore domains :"
            datastore.getMappingContext().persistentEntities.each{entity->
                println entity.javaClass.name
            }
        }
        if(datastore.class==org.grails.datastore.mapping.cassandra.CassandraDatastore){
            println "cassandra datastore domains :"
            datastore.getMappingContext().persistentEntities.each{entity->
                println entity.javaClass.name
            }
        }
        if(datastore.class==org.grails.datastore.mapping.mongo.MongoDatastore){
            println "mongodb datastore domains :"
            datastore.getMappingContext().persistentEntities.each{entity->
                println entity.javaClass.name
            }
        }
    }
```